# Select Item in ListView by Clicking Anywhere Within Item Box

Tags: c#, winforms

I am displaying items in a listview, and want them to be selectable by clicking anywhere within the row.

[image]

In task manager, clicking within a row selects the entire row. This is true regardless of which column you click in, and whether or not you click text or blank area.

In a newly made listview, a different behavior is observed:

[image]

It can only be selected by the text in the first column only. The index cannot be selected from any other column, and cannot be selected by blank space in the first column.

How can I replicate the behavior of task manager, where click (and hover, etc) events are triggered anywhere within the row?

Comment: This is correct. If you want to make an answer with that, I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As TaW said, FullRowSelect. Either change in properties or put `listView.FullRowSelect = true;` somewhere in your code.